# uwp, c# Dns.GetHostAddresses() not resolve hostname from hosts file

Tags: c#, uwp, hostname

I am working on uwp app. I edited hosts file and redirecting www.example.com to local server IP(192.168.1.187). In browser website is loading properly but in application

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses("https://www.exaple.com")[0]
```

Throws `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException`

If I remove `http`/`https`, it is working

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses("www.exaple.com")[0]
output => 192.168.1.187
```

I want to specifically make a request to `https://www.example.com`.

Comment: If you want to make a request - then make a request, not resolve hostname to IP address.

Comment: Request using httpclient and hostname to ip both are not working

Comment: You said yourself that hostname resolution is working. `https://www.example.com` is not a hostname and so cannot work with `GetHostAddress`. But `www.example.com` is hostname, and it is working.

Comment: Ok, I am using `httpClient.postAsync(url,postBodyContent)` It is working if url is  `www.example.com` but not working for `https://www.example.com` and `http://www.example.com`

Answer (score 1):

`System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses` does hostname resolution. It is very similar to `ping` in command line. You can test, that using

```
ping www.example.com
```

Will give you response while

```
ping https://www.example.com
```

will not.

As for the fact that you cannot issue a `HttpClient` request to `http://www.example.com`, it might be because you don't have the appropriate capability set. Go to **Package.appxmanifest**, click the **Capabilities** tab and check the **Private Networks (Client & Server)** capability.

Comment: Client & server capability is enabled, there is a global DNS for `https://www.example.com`. `httpClient` is working for global DNS.
For local hosts error is `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll`

Comment: I'm thinking - if GetHostAddresses works, why don't you first retrieve the IP and then do http client request to that IP directly? Doesn't that work either?